# Find out C indentation rule at point

Tags: indentation

If I recall correctly I was able to view the C indentation rules applied for indenting the line at point.

After searching the manual for a while I still can not find the command  for it. Obviously I'm missing the proper key words for my search.

Can you tell me how what the name of this command is?

Comment: Are you looking for the level of indentation at point (the function `current-column`), or are you looking for the function that determines the indentation (stored in the variable `indent-line-function`)?

Comment: I vaguely remember that this command informed me about something like: this line is indented due to "defun-open-intro" with value + or ++ or something.

Answer (score -1):

Found it myself: <kbd>M-x c-set-offset</kbd> or <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd>.

> (c-set-offset SYMBOL OFFSET &optional IGNORED)
>
> Change the value of a syntactic element symbol in `c-offsets-alist'.
> SYMBOL is the syntactic element symbol to change and OFFSET is the new
> offset for that syntactic element.

Called interactively, it proposes for SYMBOL the one applying on current line and so we can see what syntactic element governing its indentation the line belongs to.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `M-x c-show-syntactic-information` or `C-c C-s`? Note this stuff is `cc-mode` specific.

Comment: Yeah, this also does what I want. `c-set-offset` is of course rather for customizing the offset.